# YouTube API Video Update Error (when there should not be an error)

Tags: video, youtube-api

We update thousands of videos per day. Maybe one out of every 500 or so we get this error:

The request metadata is invalid. This error occurs if the request updates the snippet part of a video resource but does not set a value for both the snippet.title and snippet.categoryId properties.

Yes, I am 100% sure that both a title and category Id are being sent just like the other 499 out of 500 that work correctly.

Has anyone else run into this and discovered a way to avoid it? It seems very random and just certain videos continue to have this problem.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the "request metadata invalid" error repeatedly with the same video?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do an update, the correct method is to retrieve the current snippet object, change the values in the object  that need to be changed and then execute the update using the changed snippet object.

If you are creating a snippet object that only contains the changed values, you will get an error returned when a critical value is missing.